# Cannot Change ObservableCollection during an CollectionChanged Event

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, methods

Here's the problem:

I have a CollectionChanged Handler Method:

```
    Private Sub LayersChanged(sender As Object, e As Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
        If e.ItemCollectionHasNewItems IsNot Nothing Then
            SomethingRelatedToE.execute
        End If
    End Sub
```

I cant call *SomethingRelatedToE.excecute* because it effects *e*'s collection which causes a runtime error.

However if the *LayersChanged* method has completed I can then call *SomethingRelatedToE.execute* from another method without effecting it.

Is there a way for me to directly move to another method after the *LayersChanged* method has finished, like a Goto function or another solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this type of action isn't allowed is because it will usually result in a circular reference. When the collection is modified in the `CollectionChanged` event, the event will once again be raised, which will again modify the collection.

I would not recommend trying to work around this because it's unusual to have a collection modify itself. Try thinking of a way to do it another way.

If you need to, though, you can try using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to do your task in another thread. You'll still want to check for possible circular references and watch for race conditions.